# pandas sum data different result

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on some pandas exercises from kaggle.
I tried to solve an exercise, but I don't understand why the result is different from what I expected.

Question:

> There are only so many words you can use when describing a bottle of wine. Is a wine more likely to be "tropical" or "fruity"? Create a Series descriptor_counts counting how many times each of these two words appears in the description column in the dataset. (For simplicity, let's ignore the capitalized versions of these words.)"

My answer:

```
tropical_count= reviews["description"].str.count(pat ="tropical").sum()
fruity_count= reviews["description"].str.count(pat ="fruity").sum()

descriptor_counts = pd.Series({"tropical":tropical_count,"fruity":fruity_count},index=["tropical","fruity"])
```

Kaggle answer:

```
n_trop = reviews.description.map(lambda desc: "tropical" in desc).sum()
n_fruity = reviews.description.map(lambda desc: "fruity" in desc).sum()
descriptor_counts = pd.Series([n_trop, n_fruity], index=['tropical', 'fruity'])
```

All work great, but the results are different, does anyone know why?

My result

```py
tropical    3703
fruity      9259
dtype: int64
```

Kaggle result

```py
tropical    3607
fruity      9090
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Well, at a first glance 'in' and '=' are different operators, right?

Comment: yes, but is two different function

Comment: I don't agree with the `sum()` call at the end. Makes no sense. `Count` alone should do the job, no? (Sure, `count` will return a series, but that doesn't mean you reduce it by _summing_ everything.). Have a look in the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html

Comment: @Brandt i need to sum all the tuple for have a result of match in the string, the result without sum() is same this 

tropical: 0,1,2,0.......1 ; 
fruity: 0,0,1,0.........0

i need the sum of all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output is expected, because `str.count` counts substrings, but if use `in` operator it test only if exist value. So ouput is only `True` or `False`. Then if use `sum` boolean `True`s are processing like `1` and `False` like `0`, so ouput is different.

Sample:

```
reviews = pd.DataFrame(["Ttropical are tropical so fruity words you can",
                   "fruity ",
                   "fruity fruity",
                   "anythi"], columns=['description'])

tropical_count= reviews["description"].str.count(pat ="tropical")
fruity_count= reviews["description"].str.count(pat ="fruity")
print (tropical_count)
0    2
1    0
2    0
3    0
Name: description, dtype: int64
print (fruity_count)
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    0
Name: description, dtype: int64
```

---

```
n_trop = reviews.description.map(lambda desc: "tropical" in desc)
n_fruity = reviews.description.map(lambda desc: "fruity" in desc)
print (n_trop)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: description, dtype: bool

print (n_fruity)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: description, dtype: bool
```

Comment: you have right! Tank you so much, i think need to "counting how many times each of these two words appears" not if in any row appear or not.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: I got a different result using your code:
`n_fruity`
`0     True`
`1     True`
`2     True`
`3    False`
`Name: description, dtype: bool`

Comment: @Michał - Wrong copied Series, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

`counts(pat=..)`, counts the number of times the pattern is in the string so it can add 2 per row (or more), `tropical in desc` will evaluate true or false only counting one even if is repeated.

For instance this dataframe with two entries sums 3 under the "count" construct:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['tropical','tropicaltropical']})
df.name.str.count(pat ="tropical").sum()
```

The "in" construct will sum only 2, one per row.